# If $T$ is a normal operator over $\mathbb{C}$, it is decomposable into some self-adjoint operators $T_1, T_2$ such that $T=T_1 + iT_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Here's the full question.

[image]

I have proved (b) implies (a), already, and (a) implies (c). I just need (c) implies (b).

If you need Question $2$, it is at the bottom.

(b) implies (a) is quite obvious. (a) implies (c) can be proved using Question 2 by the Cyclic Decomposition Theorem and induction. I have trouble proving (c) implies (b). Intuitively, I feel that the strategy here is to split $g(x)=f(x)+ih(x)$, where $f(x), h(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. But I can't guarantee that the operator $f(\alpha)$ or $h(\alpha)$ is self-adjoint. Another thing I have tried is to split the operator $\alpha$ into $\frac{\alpha+\alpha^*}{2}+\frac{\alpha-\alpha^*}{2}$, but this has lead me  nowhere.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Question 2 for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

First show that $(a) \implies (b).$ Namely, if we define $\alpha_1 = \frac{\alpha+\alpha^*}2$ and $\alpha_2 = \frac{\alpha-\alpha^*}{2i}$ then show that they are self adjoint, $\alpha_1 + i\alpha_2 = \alpha$ and $\alpha_1\alpha_2 =\alpha_2\alpha_1$.

Then show $(c) \implies (a)$. Namely, if $\alpha^* = g(\alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k\alpha^k$, then clearly
$$\alpha^*\alpha = \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\alpha^k\right)\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k\alpha^{k+1} = \alpha \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\alpha^k\right) = \alpha\alpha^*$$
so $\alpha$ is normal.